# Notepad++: Add a couple of lines between existing variable lines

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of Points looking like this:

```
[-18.551,31.608,12.200] [0.998346,-0.035888,-0.044921,0.000000]
[20.000,0.000,40.000] [1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000]
[-18.551,-31.214,12.228] [0.998374,0.035057,-0.044947,0.000000]
```

The values in the first and the third line vary, the second line is always the same. Before and after these three lines there are also variable points listed.
Now I want to add some lines so that it looks like this:

```
61
[-18.551,31.608,12.200] [0.998346,-0.035888,-0.044921,0.000000]
40
50
[20.000,0.000,40.000] [1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000]
[-18.551,-31.214,12.228] [0.998374,0.035057,-0.044947,0.000000]
60
51
41
```

I was able to find the three lines with RegEx:

```
\[.*\] \[.*\]\n\[20\.000,0\.000,40\.000\] \[1\.000000,0\.000000,0\.000000,0\.000000\]\n\[.*\] \[.*\]
```

But I couldn't manage to replace it properly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are the values `61`, `40` ... constant?

Comment: yes, they are constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, just add capture groups:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\[.*\] \[.*\]\n)(\[20\.000,0\.000,40\.000\] \[1\.000000,0\.000000,0\.000000,0\.000000\]\n\[.*\] \[.*\]\n)`
- Replace with: `61\n${1}40\n50\n${2}60\n51\n41\n`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(                       # group 1, the first line
    \[.*\] \[.*\]\n
)
(                       # group 2, second and third line
    \[20\.000,0\.000,40\.000\] \[1\.000000,0\.000000,0\.000000,0\.000000\]\n
    \[.*\] \[.*\]\n
)
```

**Replacement:**

```
61\n            # 61 and linefeed
${1}            # content of group 1 (i.e. the first line)
40\n            # 40 and linefeed
50\n            # 50 and linefeed
${2}            # content of group 2, line 3 and 3
60\n            # 60 and linefeed
51\n            # 51 and linefeed
41\n            # 41 and linefeed
```

**Result for given example:**

```
61
[-18.551,31.608,12.200] [0.998346,-0.035888,-0.044921,0.000000]
40
50
[20.000,0.000,40.000] [1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000]
[-18.551,-31.214,12.228] [0.998374,0.035057,-0.044947,0.000000]
60
51
41
```

Comment: @user12530628: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)